# How to connect backend and frontend in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, architecture, microservices

In my app, I have 2 models:

```
two-model-simple-app
├── backend
│   ├── backend.iml
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── frontend
│   ├── angular.json
│   ├── dist
│   ├── frontend.iml
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── node
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   ├── target
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── tsconfig.spec.json
├── pom.xml
└── taco-cloud.iml
```

As you can see from the layout, the backend is a simple spring boot app with single class (with the main method, default spring boot src) and the frontend is angular (generate via `ng new frontend` -> the default angular src). Now the poms of root and both models:

(root)
*two-model-simple-app/pom.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>
        <module>backend</module>
        <module>frontend</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>two-model-simple-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

(backend)
*backend/pom.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>two-model-simple-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

(frontend)
*frontend/pom.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>two-model-simple-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <node.version>v12.18.2</node.version>
      <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.12.0</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>dist</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
          </includes>
        </resource>
      </resources>

      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <filesets>
              <fileset>
                <directory>dist</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>*</include>
                </includes>
              </fileset>
            </filesets>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
          <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>install node and npm</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
              </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
              <id>npm install</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>

            <execution>
              <id>npm run-script build</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now the application when issued `mvn package`, the application **PACKAGES** without issue. But when I try to run the backend as `java -jar backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, I have no frontend connected (that is, when accessing `localhost:8080/` I got 404 not page found, so the frontend is obviously not connected). So how to connect the frontend?

PS:
to show you the frontend packages correctly, there is output from `frontend/target`:

```
target
├── classes
│   └── static
│       └── frontend
│           ├── 3rdpartylicenses.txt
│           ├── favicon.ico
│           ├── index.html
│           ├── main.a485ff8e4c442418033f.js
│           ├── polyfills.4664ee786a3179f3bb93.js
│           ├── runtime.81e27cce1cc91940b6f1.js
│           └── styles.31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.css
├── frontend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
└── maven-archiver
    └── pom.properties
```

It is just not connected with the backend, even with the fact, the frontend is specified as dependency in backend pom.xml.